# switches and Locale.setDefault() not working

Tags: java, localization

I have an application that supports multiple languages. When I use:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMANY);
Application.main(args);
```

It works. but when I put it in a switch,

```
String country = "de";
Locale locale = null;
switch(country) {
case "de":
  locale = Locale.GERMANY;
break;
....more cases and locales.
}

Locale.setDefault(locale);
Application.main(args);
```

it fails. I'm flabbergasted. I've tried alternatives like setting the Locale directly within the switch, or setting it directly in the switch AND calling the main method. No go. It's just weird. I'm on J7u60, Windows 7. Please help.

Comment: _it fails_ explain more

Comment: ... ideally with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: it displays in English, which is my system locale. but when I do it directly, without switches, it comes out in German.

Comment: where do you set `country`?

Comment: it's just for example. but I'll amend the OP. edit: the program enters the switch, into the correct case, but when app is up, it's in English.

Comment: I didn't bother getting to the bottom of this and used command line arguments to get where I want the application to go. Thanks anyway everyone